# Is it possible to manage the maximum length of my Alerts' Title? (it displays a truncated title)

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, workflow, alert

I've got a workflow in Sharepoint Designer 2010, that sends me email, when something is changed on my site.

My only problem is, that the email's subject length is correct, long enough, but My alerts title is truncated. It displays only "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lege... has been added".

Are there any solution which can help me to write out the whole paragraph, or at least more than these few words?

Answer (score 0):

No, Outlook always truncates the length of the subject that it displays in the toaster popup to make sure it fits.